# Transform request object to array for database insert

Tags: php, laravel-5

i have made a duplicable form input using jquery, how do i insert all data

```
    <tbody id="visites">
    <tr id="ligne">
    <td> <input type... name="id[]"></td>
    <td> <input type... name="date[]"></td>
    <td> <input type... name="statut[]"></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function dupliquer()
      {
        $( "#ligne" ).clone().appendTo( "#visites" );
      }
    </script>
```

This is the request bag

```
        id  
          0 "1"
          1 "1"
          2 "1"
          3 "1"
        date    
          0 null
          1 null
          2 null
          3 null
        statut  
          0 null
          1 null
          2 null
          3 null
```

The model fillable are

```
['id','date','statut']
```

I want to transform the request() bag to something like that

```
    $data = [
             {id:1,date:'..',statut:'3'},
             {id:1,date:'..',statut:'3'},
             {id:1,date:'..',statut:'3'}
            ]
```

and perform this :

```
    foreach($data as ....)
    { 
      Model::create([...]);
    }
```

Summarly this is the request bag 
[Request bag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3WTVa.png)
And this is what i want
[Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8u5s7.png)
I hope i'v been clear ^^ thanks.

Comment: ....and what keeps you from writing code for that?

Comment: i don't know how

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try doing this

```
$dataArray = [];
foreach($request['id'] as $key => $value){
   // create new empty object
   $ob = new \stdClass;
   $ob->id = $request['id'][$key];
   $ob->date = $request['date'][$key];
   $ob->status = $request['statut'][$key];

   // push the new object to the array
   $dataArray[] = $ob;
}
```